# JSF 2.0 web.xml error page status code

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf-2, web.xml

I'm currently modifying an application that I created using JSF. For some background on what I  am doing please read below.

**Background**

Acunetix scan is detecting a medium security problem called "Application error message" in most of my pages when it manipulates the value of javax.faces.ViewState. The Acunetix scan changes the viewstate to a random value or an empty string that causes my application to throw an exception. The exceptions are caught by a custom error page using the following configuration in the web.xml file.

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>/unhandled.xhtml</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
  <location>/unhandled.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

This works as intended and the custom error page is shown. However, Acunetix scan is considering this as vulnerability because it is seeing the 500 status code  in the header with the error message Internal Server Error.

Acunetix scan excerpt

```
/webapp/login.xhtml
Details
URL encoded Post input javax.faces.ViewState was set to
Error message found: Internal Server Error
```

**Question:**

Is it possible to change the status code of the error page to 200 instead of 500. If not can anyone suggest a work around that will allow me to manipulate the page status code.

**Note:**

Please note that im using the following frameworks
Spring, JSF 2.0, Primefaces 3.4, Hibernate, Omnifaces(FacesEceptionFilter & FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory), Tomcat 7 server.

Thanks for your help...

Comment: I don't think so, but the most obvious question is did you try?  That is, did you change the 200 to 500 in web.xml?  If so, did it have the desired effect?

Comment: @EJK thanks for the comment but what I actually want (as workaround) is for the error page to have a response header of 200 as it is currently at 500.

Comment: @EJK Anyways I replaced the error code to 200 and removed the java.lang.Throwable exception type so I can try your suggestion. I was just redirected to the default 404 not to my custom error page because the error code does not match.

Comment: See my answer answer below.  I think a servlet filter is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by doing this. In my error page I just added an event listener that force the status code to 200.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

       <f:view contentType="text/html">
          <f:metadata>
             <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{errorController.forceStatusCode200()}"></f:event>
          </f:metadata>

          <h:body>
             <h1>ZZZZZZZZZ</h1>
          </h:body>
       </f:view>
    </html>
```

In my managedBean

```
@component("errorController")
@Scope("view")
public class ErrorController
{
   public void forceStatusCode200()
   {
      FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
      ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
      HttpServletResponse hp = (HttpServletResponse) ec.getResponse();
      hp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
   }
}
```

By doing this when i check the status code of the response using Fiddler I can no longer see the error code 500.

I hope this helps someone. Also if anyone can point out any undesired side effects please don't hesitate to post.

Thanks for your time...

Comment: I will leave this question unanswered for a few days in case someone has a better answer.

Comment: Or just `ec.setResponseStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);`.

Comment: Without an extra backing bean:

     <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{facesContext.externalContext.response.setStatus(200)}"/>

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a servlet filter that unconditionally sets all response codes to 200.

1. Register your filter in web.xml as follows:

   <`filter`>

   ```
       <filter-name>StatusCodeFilter</filter-name>

       <filter-class>com.foo.StatusCodeFilter</filter-class>
   ```

   <`/filter`>
2. In the doFilter method of your filter class, set the response code as follows:

   ```
      @Override
      public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) 
          throws IOException, ServletException {

              ((HttpServletResponse)response).setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
   ```

Comment: Hi, just tested your idea unfortunately it does not seem to work.As I also need to call the chain.doFilter() method. if I set the status before the chain.dofilter() the status code is overwritten. I also tried setting the status code after catching the error thrown by the chain.dofilter() it is still overwritten. I assume that it is overwritten in the applicationfilter or errorvalve from tomcat, if I re throw the exception. If I do not re throw the exception the status code is set to 200 but only a blank page is shown and not the custom error page. Do you have any other ideas??