# Hide/customize status 500 error message/status description inside response header (Glassfish)

Tags: java, jsf-2, glassfish

I'm developing jsf 2 web app which runs under GlassFish (v3.1.2.2). This app has custom error 500 page which is defined in web.xml. My question is whether there is a possibility to disable/hide/customize error message/status description inside response header for status 500 response? Currently I'm getting something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 /view.xhtml @11,30 [error message same as in root exception] <- I want to hide this one (only message/status description)
X-Powered-By: JSF/2.0
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 09 Jan 2014 15:33:44 GMT
Connection: close
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. It is not nice but it works. See
[JSF 2.0 web.xml error page status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341269/jsf-2-0-web-xml-error-page-status-code/20370847#20370847).

Instead of changing status code I leave status code as it is and change only status message:

```
...
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
HttpServletResponse hp = (HttpServletResponse) ec.getResponse();
hp.setStatus(hp.getStatus(), "my new message");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a filter on web.xml to intercept the error and generate the response you like.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info

Comment: This does not work unfortunately. Response header for error page is set after filter invocation, and no filter is being invoked on error page request... So I can catch servlet exception inside `doFilter` method and define my header, but this gets overridden afterwards :(

Comment: Are you setting the headers after the call to chain.doFilter?

Comment: Yes, and only if `ServletException` is thrown while `chain.doFilter()` method

Comment: Maybe that if is the problem.

Comment: I think the problem is that GlassFish does all the error page handling things after filter invocation. The error page itself does not appear inside the filter either.